# Dataloader update of Opportunity Products is not firing trigger

Tags: trigger, data-loader

I have a very simple `before insert, before update` trigger on the OpportunityLineItem object that updates a couple of field values based on other fields. When I update an Opportunity Product record in my browser (by clicking edit and save without changing anything), the trigger works just fine and updates the two fields. But when I run a Data Loader update on a collection of OpportunityLineItem IDs, the `Contract_Duration__c` field is not getting updated. Why would this be?

Here is the trigger code:

```
trigger OpportunityLineItemTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (before insert, before update) {

    List<Product2> allProducts = [SELECT Id, Revenue_Type__c FROM Product2];

    Map<Id, String> productRevenueTypeMap = new Map<Id, String>();

    for (Product2 p : allProducts) productRevenueTypeMap.put(p.id, p.Revenue_Type__c);

    Map<Decimal, String> contractDurationMap = new Map<Decimal, String>{
        0 => 'End Date Same as Start Date',
        1 => 'One Month',
        3 => 'One Quarter',
        6 => 'Six Months',
        12 => 'One Year',
        18 => '18 Months',
        24 => 'Two Years',
        36 => 'Three Years',
        48 => 'Four Years',
        60 => 'Five Years'
    };

    for(OpportunityLineItem o : trigger.new) {
        o.Product_Revenue_Type__c = productRevenueTypeMap.get(o.Product2Id);
        if (o.Number_of_months__c != NULL && contractDurationMap.containsKey(o.Number_of_months__c)){
            o.Contract_duration__c = contractDurationMap.get(o.Number_of_months__c);
        } else {
            o.Contract_duration__c = 'Other';
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Put in system.debugs and see where it's breaking, or even if its getting in at alll

Comment: best practice -- use `oli` as the loop variable rather than `o` to avoid confusing the reader as to what is being implicitly updated. That said, are you saying that `o.contract_duration__c` is NULL?

Comment: What's happening now is that there are a bunch of Opportunity Products where o.contract_duration__c ended up as "Other" due to some interference from a deprecated workflow rule. I've cleared that problem, and when I go and manually update one of these records (without editing anything), the trigger works fine and updates the field to the correct value. But, when I run a data loader update on the full set of these records, they do not get updated.

Comment: Ultimately I realized that I can accomplish most of this with Workflow Rules. It's eleven workflow rules, so it's not pretty but in the end it will actually work.